# How to get neighboring buffer numbers

Tags: buffers

Lets pretend I have a Vim session with buffers that look like this:

```
+-------------+--------------+
|             |              |
|             |              |
|             |              |
|             |              |
|             |              |
|      1      |       2      |
|             |              |
|             |              |
|             |              |
|             |              |
|             |              |
+-------------+--------------+
```

Is there a way to query which buffer is to the right of buffer #1?

Ideally, I'd want something like this (Obviously this isn't Vimscript but I hope it gives you the idea):

```
get_neighboring_buffers(current_buffer=1, direction="right")
# Result: [2]
```

And then consider this window layout

```
+-------------+--------------+
|             |              |
|             |              |
|             |      2       |
|             |              |
|             |              |
|      1      +--------------+
|             |              |
|             |              |
|             |      3       |
|             |              |
|             |              |
+-------------+--------------+
```

In this case, the same function might return more than one buffer:

```
get_neighboring_buffers(current_buffer=1, direction="right")
# Result: [2, 3]
```

Alternatively, is there a way to check which buffer is more "on-top" of another?

```
get_topmost_buffer([2, 3])
# Result: 2
```

I'm trying to find the nearest-right buffer for a script I'm writing but am
having trouble finding resources about this online.

Ideally, the solution should be able to handle the 3-buffer setup I showed but
if it only works with the first example (the vertical split) then that's fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this [Get_right_buffers()](https://0x0.st/sg57.txt) function and this [Get_topmost_buffer()](https://0x0.st/sg5h.txt) function do what you want?

Comment: Those two functions are exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to query which buffer is to the right of buffer #1?

I'm not sure it's reliable, but you could try this function:

```
fu! Get_right_buffers() abort
    let right_edge = win_screenpos(0)[1] + winwidth(0)
    return filter(map(filter(getwininfo(),
        \ {i,v -> v.tabnr == tabpagenr()}),
        \ {i,v -> v.wincol == right_edge + 1 ? getwininfo()[i].bufnr : -1}),
        \ {i,v -> v != -1})
endfu
```

`getwininfo()` gives you information about all the windows of all the tabpages.

The purpose of the innermost `filter()` invocation is to remove the information about the windows in the other tabpages.
The purpose of the `map()` invocation is to convert those information into the numbers of the buffers whose left edge is next to the right edge of the current window.

For more information, see:

```
:h win_screenpos()
:h winwidth()
:h filter()
:h map()
:h getwininfo()
:h tabpagenr()
```

---

Alternatively, if your Vim version includes the patch [8.1.0307](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.0307) you could try to use the `winlayout()` function.

You would have to parse the nested list it returns to get the information you want.

From `:h winlayout()`:

```
winlayout([{tabnr}])                                        *winlayout()*
            The result is a nested List containing the layout of windows
            in a tabpage.

            Without {tabnr} use the current tabpage, otherwise the tabpage
            with number {tabnr}. If the tabpage {tabnr} is not found,
            returns an empty list.

            For a leaf window, it returns:
                    ['leaf', {winid}]
            For horizontally split windows, which form a column, it
            returns:
                    ['col', [{nested list of windows}]]
            For vertically split windows, which form a row, it returns:
                    ['row', [{nested list of windows}]]

            Example:
                    " Only one window in the tab page
                    :echo winlayout()
                    ['leaf', 1000]
                    " Two horizontally split windows
                    :echo winlayout()
                    ['col', [['leaf', 1000], ['leaf', 1001]]]
                    " Three horizontally split windows, with two
                    " vertically split windows in the middle window
                    :echo winlayout(2)
                    ['col', [['leaf', 1002], ['row', ['leaf', 1003],
                                         ['leaf', 1001]]], ['leaf', 1000]]
```

---

> Alternatively, is there a way to check which buffer is more "on-top" of another?

You could try this function:

```
fu! Get_topmost_buffer(a,b) abort
    if bufwinnr(a:a) == -1
        return 'buffer '.a:a.' is not displayed in this tabpage'
    elseif bufwinnr(a:b) == -1
        return 'buffer '.a:b.' is not displayed in this tabpage'
    elseif win_screenpos(bufwinnr(a:a))[0] == win_screenpos(bufwinnr(a:b))[0]
        return 'the windows of buffer '.a:a.' and '.a:b.' are at the same level'
    else
        return win_screenpos(bufwinnr(a:a))[0] > win_screenpos(bufwinnr(a:b))[0]
            \ ? a:b
            \ : a:a
    endif
endfu
```

For more information, see:

```
:h bufwinnr()
:h win_screenpos()
```